# Unable to load the mojo 'execute' in the gmaven-plugin plugin

Tags: java-11, gmaven-plugin

I upgraded java-8 to java-11 and since then I got an error on gmaven-plugin:

> Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.maven.plugin.execute.ExecuteMojo.(Unknown Source)
>     while locating org.codehaus.groovy.maven.plugin.execute.ExecuteMojo
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (tmp-id) on project project-name: Execution tmp-id of goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute failed: Unable to load the mojo 'execute' in the plugin 'org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tmp-id</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>
                            println 'Hello'
                        </source>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem and i didn't find solution

Comment: I solved it by using gmavenplus-plugin instead of gmaven-plugin:<groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
<artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7.1</version>

Comment: thanks i will try it